# GPO: Applying a home page to Win7 and Vista Clients running IE9

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, group-policy, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to set the homepage on several Windows 7 and Vista machines via Group Policy Preferences. Both are running Internet Explorer 9. The "apply once and do not reapply" option is enabled, as i want the users to be able to override the companies default.

However the homepage does not get applied. Having a look at gpresult at the client side, I can see several IE settings coming from another GPO by "Internet Explorer Maintenance" - settings. This confuses me. My GPO has been created on a W2012 R2 machine, therefor no IEM settings show up. I can see that the GPO gets applied, but no preferences. I have enabled the relevant home page part by pressing F6!

Is there some admx version mismatch? How can I fix this? Thanks for your input!

Comment: Right-click the GPO and select Enforced.  Do a gpupdate /force on the workstation then try it again.  Report results back to me.